# use operation logic inside SQL Query?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a Query string inside Employees Page that read URL Parameter 
to get Companies employees from DataBase if parameter is ***ALL*** the page should display **ALL** Employees but if ***CompID*** Equal Specific ID it will Get only Employees for this Company to do that i am using two queries but i am sure that i can use only one query to get the same result
my Query String Parameter is :

```
String CompID = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["CompID"]);
```

The SQL Query to display ALL Employee is :

```
Query1 = "SELECT TbEmp.empID, TbEmp.fName, TbEmp.lName, TbEmp.email," +
               " TbEmp.phoneNbr, TbEmp.compID, TbEmp.gender, " +
                "TbEmp.address, TbComp.compName From TbEmp" +
                " INNER JOIN TbComp on TbComp.compID = TbEmp.compID ORDER BY TbComp.compID"
```

The SQL Query to Display Employees for specific companie is :

```
Query2 = "SELECT TbEmp.empID, TbEmp.fName, TbEmp.lName, TbEmp.email," +
        " TbEmp.phoneNbr, TbEmp.compID, TbEmp.gender, " +
        "TbEmp.address, TbComp.compName From TbEmp" +
        " INNER JOIN TbComp on TbComp.compID = TbEmp.compID WHERE TbEmp.compID = @CompID ORDER BY TbComp.compID DESC"
```

**Can someone help me to merge those two queries in one query ?**

Comment: Sql query is different from jquery?

Comment: yes they are totally different Sql query is used to perform actions inside database and Jquery is used on the client side to control page or send data to server side using ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is a simple or-and case. Assuming your @CompID is numeric and you can send a zero to indicate the 'All' search...

```
INNER JOIN TbComp on TbComp.compID = TbEmp.compID 
WHERE (@CompID = 0) or (@CompID <> 0 and TbEmp.compID = @CompID) 
ORDER BY TbComp.compID DESC"
```

Comment: thank you for your help Vanquished Wombat the query work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Although I would not suggest using queries to write your logic in asp.net (use stored procedures with parameters instead).
You can do this :

**Solution 1 :**

```
string Query1 = "SELECT TbEmp.empID, TbEmp.fName, TbEmp.lName, TbEmp.email," +
               " TbEmp.phoneNbr, TbEmp.compID, TbEmp.gender, " +
                "TbEmp.address, TbComp.compName From TbEmp" +
                " INNER JOIN TbComp on TbComp.compID = TbEmp.compID " ;

String CompID = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["CompID"]);
if( CompID<>"")
{
  Query1 += " WHERE TbEmp.compID = " + CompID //Beware : Chance of injection
}
Query1 +=" ORDER BY TbComp.compID";
```

**Solution 2 :** Assuming @CompID will be passed null if it is not there.

```
Query2 = "SELECT TbEmp.empID, TbEmp.fName, TbEmp.lName, TbEmp.email," +
        " TbEmp.phoneNbr, TbEmp.compID, TbEmp.gender, " +
        "TbEmp.address, TbComp.compName From TbEmp" +
        " INNER JOIN TbComp on TbComp.compID = TbEmp.compID WHERE
     TbEmp.compID = Isnull(@CompID, TbEmp.compID)  ORDER BY TbComp.compID DESC"
```